# Is there a way to give write permissions only in a transaction in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I work with a software that is used by a lot of different clients in several countries, with different needs, rules and constraints on their data.

When I make a change to the database's structure, I have a tool to test it on every client's database, obviously with read-only rights. This means that the best way to test a query like `UPDATE table SET x = y WHERE condition`
is to call the "read-only part" `SELECT x FROM table WHERE condition`.
It works but it's not ideal, as sometimes it is writing data that causes problems (mostly deadlocks or timeouts), meaning I can't see the problem until a client suffers from it.

I'm wondering if there is a way to grant write permissions in Postgres, but only when inside a transaction, and force a rollback on every transaction. This way, changes could be tested accurately on real data and still prevent any dev from editing it.
Any ideas?

Edit: the volumes are too large to consider cloning data for every dev who needs to run a query

Comment: I don't think you can do that with permissions. It's on your testing tool to run the commands in a transaction and to guarantee it'll be rolled back. The closest I can think of would be to grant view-only permissions, create temporary tables as clones of everything in the database, and try your update commands on those temp tables - but that would be rather expensive.

Comment: You're right, it's more the testing tool's responsibility. It is really only replicating what Postgres does on several databases at once and gathering the data. Maybe it doesn't suit our needs anymore. I was asking for an "easy" solution that could be implemented quickly, but I'll ask the team who made the tool if they can update it and make this possible...

Comment: A deadlock is always a transient problem, so you won't be able to test for it. Much better than trying to test beforehand if a certain data modification will work is to actually perform it and handle the error if it fails. Constraints will cause an error if the data are not consistent.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds similar to creating an audit table to record information about transactions. I would consider using a [trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/triggers.html) to write a copy of the data to a "rollback" table/row and then copy the "rollback" table/row back on completion of the update.

Comment: Maybe I should've mentioned it, but the bigger databases have tens of millions of rows, and in rare cases a single row can weigh up to a kB (yes there are structural problems in this database, unfortunately it's not my job to correct them). There are often several developers using the tool at once, so we don't have the resources to copy such amounts of data. Besides, this is production data that is used at the same time to run the client's website, so we can't move it around even for a second